# Can Latin migrō-migrāre and/or meō-meāre be the origin of Romanian "merge" - "mere" (to go, walk)?

Tags: etymology

Trying to plead that this is not off-topic here:

- I am trying to ask a theoretical question about the rules behind the selection between opposing hypotheses.
- I don't want to ask something of the form "what is the origin of the word X?", nor "what is the case, what are the facts with X?" but rather: "what are the rules that would dictate that X is more probable than Y?" and  "given the facts, isn't X more probable than Y?"

---

The "accepted" etymology (the one I have found again and again in Romanian and other sources) of Romanian word [*a merge*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/merge#Romanian), the most common word for "to walk, to go to", is, like in Wiktionary:

> Inherited from Latin *[mergere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mergere#Latin)*, present active infinitive of *[mergō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mergo#Latin)*
> (itself ultimately from Proto-Indo-European **[mesg](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/mesg-)-* (“to plunge,
> dip”)), with a unique sense developing in Balkanic or Eastern Romance.
> Compare Aromanian [*njergu, njeardziri*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/njergu#Aromanian); cf. also Albanian *[mërgoj](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%ABrgoj#Albanian)* (“to
> move away”) and Sardinian *imbergere* (“to push”). There may have been
> an intermediate sense of "to fall" in earlier Romanian.

While Aromanian [njergu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/njergu#Aromanian) (to walk) is thus to be grouped with Romanian *merge, merg*, Albanian [*mërgoj*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%ABrgoj#Albanian) (“to move away”) is

> Probably borrowed through Vulgar Latin from Latin *migrāre*, with
> metathesis. Cf. also *mergō*, *mergere* and Romanian *merge* (“to go”).

But [*mergere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mergere#Latin) (*mergo* - rhotacized form of Proto-Italic **mezgō*, from Proto-Indo-European **mesg-* (“to plunge, dip”) ) has nothing to do with [*migrare*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/migro#Latin) (*migro* - from Proto-Italic **migrāō*, from Proto-Indo-European **h₂migʷ-* (“to change”), from **h₂mey-*. Cognate with Ancient Greek ἀμείβω (ameíbō).)

*Migro*, instead, seems related to Latin *[*meō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meo#Latin)* ("to go along, pass or traverse", from Proto-Italic **meā*, from Proto-Indo-European *mey*), present infinitive *meāre*, which is used also in [Italian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meare#Italian) (and in [Dante](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/meare/)), and has a very close form and meaning to the Transylvanian form (*mere*) of Romanian "to go, walk (*merge*).

- mergo < Proto-Italic *mezgō < PIE *mesg- (“to plunge, dip”).
- meo < Proto-Italic *meā, < PIE [*mey](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/mey-#Root_3) (root 1.3: "to change
  to exchange,to change places → to go past")
- migro < Proto-Italic *migrāō < PIE [*h₂migʷ-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%82meyg%CA%B7-) (to change, exchange, to change places → to wander) : Wiktionary says "Perhaps an extension of *h₂mey-", which links to [*mey](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/mey-).

---

Is it the form of the Romanian word "merge" (namely /g/) which forbids its relation to *meō - meāre* and pushes in favor of the origin from *mergere*?

But isn't the Albanian connection very probable? And in that case isn't *meo/meare* and *migro-migrare* much more probable as an origin? How can the connection between the Romanian [*merge*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/merge#Romanian) and Albanian [*mërgoj*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%ABrgoj#Albanian) be justified (within the Balkanic Romance) while at the same time pretending an origin from *mergere*?

Comment: Did you mean to say that _migrō_ is related to Latin _meō_? I don’t think there’s any sensible way to relate _mergō_ (< _*mesg-_) and _meō_ (< _*h₂migʷ-r-_, extended from _*h₂mei̯-_) to each other.

Comment: That's what I understand him as saying...

Comment: @LjL I was referring specifically to the paragraph that starts with, “_Mergo_, instead, is related to Latin _meō_” – I expect that should read, “_Migrō_, instead, is related to Latin _meō_”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I'm very sorry, I have now corrected it: it's "migro", not "mergo". The idea being that ultimately "meo" and "migro" may come from  PIE root "mey" (to change - change place). My idea being that *meo* and *migro* are part of a morphological and semantic "space" that seems closer to Romanian *merge/mere* than *mergo*. Albanian form should in fact plead against  the connection *merge/mere* - *mergo*.